# Autowired Service is null in specific methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application where, suddenly, the autowired services returning null at specific methods.

Here is a code snippet for the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@CrossOrigin
public class UserManagementController {

  @Autowired
  private UserService userService;

  ...

  @PostMapping("/register")
  private GameInfo register(@RequestBody UserInfo userInfo) {
    User user = new User();
    ...
    user.setUsername("user-" + userService.count());
    ...
    return gameController.getGameInfo(user);
  }

  ...

  @PostMapping("/statistics")
  public StatisticsInfo statistics(
        @RequestParam(name = "username", required = true) String username,
        Authentication authentication) {
    User user = userService.findByUsername(username);
    ...
  }
}
```

The `userService` is null in the first method, and works fine in the second one.

**UPDATE:**
Here is the code snippet for the UserService which is null in "register" method.

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    public long count() {
        return repository.count();
    }    
    ...
}
```

The `userService` has normal CRUD methods.
Kindly note that the userService is null, so a NullPointerException is thrown when I invoke any of its methods.

**UPDATE 2:**

I have created a clone of the faulty method `register` and named it `dontRegister`, this magically solved the issue of `register` but introduced the same issue in the new method.

I don't understand the logic behind this, as it seems that I always need to add one extra unused method.

I'll keep the question open until maybe someone comes up with an explanation.

Comment: Are you sure that the second method is not overridden in a subclass? (i.e. are you sure that that code actually runs?)

Comment: Sadly, yes. I reviewed it and tested it in postman many times before I got frustrated and post a question here.
Also, there are no subclasses for this controller

Comment: What do you mean "returns null"? From the count() method?

Comment: You havn't included the constructor or any other place where the field can be set in your code. Is it possible that this second method is called before the field is initialized?

Comment: @daniu the "userService" itself is null, not the count() method.

Comment: @Pieter12345 there are no constructors, this is a RESTful application.

Comment: what is there in userService.count() method . Please check if you are returning ```return null``` in ```count()``` method . I'm telling this bcoz I made this mistake many times.Please check the flow in ```count()``` method

Comment: @Umeshwaran Thank you for your comment, I posted the UserService code which basically contains CRUD methods. However, it is the "UserService" object which is null, not the "count()" method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your register method is `private`, make it `public`. Logically it should be public anyway as it is called from outside the package.

Comment: Very good catch, this is probably the issue. I will check again and get back to mark this as a correct answer. Thanks

Comment: "register" method is still private but now it's working after adding the "dontRegister" method. It doesn't make sense to me yet, but I'll accept this answer.